# Module that requires buffer fails to work after successful compilation

Tags: commonjs, svelte, rollupjs

I'm trying to use [base58](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs58) that imports `buffer`. I've installed both:

- https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/rollup-plugin-node-builtins
- https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/rollup-plugin-node-globals

and added them in the plugin list, but buffer seems to not be defined. I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing here to be honest, using those two abandoned packages seems more complicated than expected.

I can provide an example if needed, but maybe it's something easy that already has a simple answer.

My `rollup.config.js` is the following (I've removed some parts that are not important):

```js
import alias from "@rollup/plugin-alias";
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";
import json from "rollup-plugin-json";
import globals from "rollup-plugin-node-globals";
import builtins from "rollup-plugin-node-builtins";
import svelte from "rollup-plugin-svelte";
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import livereload from "rollup-plugin-livereload";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";

// ...

export default [
  {
    input: "src/background/",
    output: {
      sourcemap: true,
      format: "iife",
      name: "background",
      file: "build/background/bundle.js"
    },
    plugins: [
      builtins(),
      globals(),

      // If you have external dependencies installed from
      // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
      // some cases you'll need additional configuration —
      // consult the documentation for details:
      // https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs
      resolve({
        browser: true,
        dedupe: importee =>
          importee === "svelte" || importee.startsWith("svelte/")
      }),
      commonjs(),

      // Watch the `build` directory and refresh the
      // browser on changes when not in production
      //! production && livereload("build"),

      // If we're building for production (npm run build
      // instead of npm run dev), minify
      production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
      clearScreen: true,
      chokidar: {
        usePolling: true
      }
    }
  }];
```

Comment: After digging in the dependencies I noticed that the problem was not the buffer implementation provided by `rollup-plugin-node-globals` but the usage of `base58`.

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score -2):

For browser usage, [their README](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/bs58#browser) says to use Browserify.

For Buffer compatibility, Browserify [says](https://github.com/browserify/browserify#compatibility) it uses [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer).

And indeed, this seems to work without hurdle ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6eeeb2a62cd24124a6f7758a329ce0fe?version=3.16.3)):

```html
<script>
    import { default as bs58 } from 'bs58'

    // the woes of importing CJS in ESM...
    import { default as B } from 'buffer'
    const { Buffer } = B

    const bytes = Buffer.from('003c176e659bea0f29a3e9bf7880c112b1b31b4dc826268187', 'hex')
    const address = bs58.encode(bytes)

    const out = bs58.decode(address)
    const decoded = out.toString('hex')
</script>

{address}   => {decoded}
```

You should try to install the `buffer` package locally and use that in your app.

Comment: After playing around with a subset of my code I was able to successfully compile my code for the browser without using Browserify.

Comment: Great! What I was suggesting was to install the `buffer` package, not to use Browserify. It seems that bs58 module can also be used with ArrayBuffer, but I've not confirmed. Is this what you have done? Maybe post your solution as an answer here for others?

Comment: @vrde can you give a description of how you got it to work. I am having the same issue.